# Apache2 Restarting every 1min and 3 seconds - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4

It's pretty much in the title. I've tried everything I can think of but Apache2 is doing a restart every 1min and 3seconds - without fail. It's not doing a graceful restart, as every time it restarts the client can not connect, and are met with "This site can't be reached" in Chrome.

This is happening on a VPS hosted on Linode with the Ubuntu 16.04 image. As far as I know everything was setup as default. (I inherited the site, but trying to figure out this odd issue. )

Apache is version 2.4.18.

PHP is version 7.0.30

The site does not see a lot of traffic (maybe 1k hits/month) - so traffic should not be causing this either.

Below are the logs that I'm seeing from the Apache2 error.log

```
[Mon Aug 27 23:04:56.015029 2018] [core:notice] [pid 32672] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:56.492903 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32672] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.000463 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.001156 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.1"; loaded version="1.5.2"
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.001857 2018] [:warn] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: Loaded APR do not match with compiled!
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.001959 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.35 "; loaded version="8.38 2015-11-23"
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.002041 2018] [:warn] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: Loaded PCRE do not match with compiled!
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.002155 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.002230 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: YAJL compiled version="2.1.0"
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.002300 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.2"
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.002460 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call: "2.9.0,Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu),1.5.1/1.5.2,8.35/8.38 2015-11-23,Lua 5.1,2.9.2,<removed_for_SO>"
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.060493 2018] [:notice] [pid 32730] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call successfully sent. For more information visit: http://status.modsecurity.org/
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:58.105989 2018] [:notice] [pid 32734] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 32734)
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:59.016019 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32731] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 27 23:05:59.017563 2018] [core:notice] [pid 32731] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Aug 27 23:06:59.489457 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32731] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I see the issues with APR and PCRE not having the same version, but I had read in a different thread that this should not be causing the issue I am seeing.

If there is anything else I can setup to help figure this out - that would be appreciated, or if someone else has run across something similar that would be helpful too.

I've already tried looking at HTOP to see what processes are running - nothing out of the ordinary there, I do see a CPU spike AFTER I see the restart command (Which makes sense given apache is restarting)

We do have logrotate installed (another common thing I have seen) however logrotate is set to run weekly, so I don't think that its causing this either.

We're hosting wordpress on the site as well.

Let me know if there is anything else I can add to this that might help.

EDIT: Checked on cronjobs as well - no cronjobs

Comment: some cron job gone rogue ?

Comment: No cronjob. Edited my original post to be more helpful with that as well.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ probably a better place to ask